# Resharper - VisualStudio 2012 Custom Shortcut to Replace Selection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-8.0

In the web project I have been working on, we have string literals all over like

```
<div class="title">This is Title</div>
<div class="text">This is some text<div>
```

In order to make the application multilingual, I need to replace all these literals to some helper methods:

```
<div class="title">@TranslationHelper.Translate("This is Title")</div>
<div class="text">@TranslationHelper.Translate("This is some text")<div>
```

I want to create a custom shortcut (e.g CTRL + ALT + M) either through Resharper 8.0 or Visual Studio 2012.

When I select the text I want to transform and press the shortcut I defined, Visual studio should replace the selection with the format I defined.

How do I do that?

Comment: That's just a regex replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Resharpers `Surround With` feature to acheive this. First open the Template Explorer

> Resharper -> Template Explorer

then click New Template:

[image]

Enter your desired string in the template editor and save (Ctrl-S)

[image]

Now place your cursor in the desired text. On another note you can use Resharpers `Extend Selection` feature to quickly select the text (Shortcut is Ctrl-Alt-RightArrow)

Once the text is selected choose press Ctrl-E,U  (Resharper Surround with)

[image]

Click More where you can select your new template and ensure you add it to the quicklist so its added to the list for next time

[image]

[image]